# Promise resolves before loop completes in sails

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have a list of posts containing `userId`. When fetching n no.of post, I want to loop throught and get and fetch user data and append them into the post.

But before the loop gets resolved, the function gets return with `undefined`. After that, the post data gets listed but I want the post data to be fetched first.

I am new to promises and async. If there are any other solutions that I can use, then please notify me.

I am using sailsjs.

```
fetchPosts: async (req, res) => {

let feeds = [];

posts = await Posts.find({
  skip: offset,
  limit: limit,
  sort: sort,
});
if (posts) {
  /**
   * LOOPING THROUGH FETCHED POST LOOP TO GET
   * USER DATA, LIKE, SHARE, FOLLOW, BOOKMARKS
   */

  const functionWithPromise = (post) => {
    //a function that returns a promise

    console.log(feeds);
    return Promise.resolve(post);
  };

  const anotherAsyncFunction = async (post) => {
    return functionWithPromise(post);
  };

  const getUser = async (userId, post) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const user = await Account.findOne({ id: userId });
      if (user) {
        post = {
          ...post,
          user: {
            id: user.id,
            uName: user.uName,
            provider: user.provider,
            dpURL: user.dpURL,
            provider: user.provider,
          },
        };

        resolve(post);
      } else {
        reject(null);
      }
    });
  };

  const anAsyncFunction = async (post) => {
    if (post.isAdminPost) {
      post = {
        ...post,
        user: {
          id: "5f3b8bf00dc3f12414b7f773", // this is usedid of admin@dopaminetalks.com in `Admin` model
          uName: "DTOfficial",
          provider: "LOCAL",
          dpURL: "/dpURL/86a73b80-babc-4caa-a84c-762f6e9c1b36.png",
        },
      };
      feeds = [...feeds, post];
      return anotherAsyncFunction(feeds);
    } else {
      getUser(post.userId, post).then((post) => {
        feeds = [...feeds, post];

        return anotherAsyncFunction(feeds);
      });
    }
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    return Promise.all(posts.map((post) => anAsyncFunction(post)));
  };

  getData().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return res.json({
      status: true,
      msg: "Posts Fetched",
      data: data,
    });
  });
}
},
```

Comment: The else clause in `anAsyncFunction()` is missing a `return`.

Comment: there is a return to anotherAsyncFunction(feeds)

Comment: There's a return inside the `.then()` but the promise returned by the whole `getUser(....).then(....)` expression needs to be returned, otherwise `anAsyncFunction()` returns `undefined` whenever it hits that `else` clause. Hence the behaviour you describe.

Comment: You can write `return getUser(post.userId, post).then(post => functionWithPromise([...feeds, post]));`

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!